# Assign sprite to sprite renderer from another class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am attempting to assign one sprite from a Class A (Dress.cs) to a sprite renderer of a Class B (Body.cs). All what I have is:

*NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Dress.OnTriggerEnter2D (UnityEngine.Collider2D collision) (at Assets/Scripts/Dress Scripts/Dress.cs:25)*

Here is the code:
**Body.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Body : MonoBehaviour
{
    private SpriteRenderer bodyRenderer;

    private void Awake()
    {
        bodyRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    public SpriteRenderer GetBodyRenderer
    {
        get { return bodyRenderer; }
        set { bodyRenderer = value; }
    }

    public void SetBodySprite(Sprite inputSprite)
    {
        bodyRenderer.sprite = inputSprite;
    }
}
```

And **Dress.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Dress : MonoBehaviour
{

    private CircleCollider2D dressCollider;
    private SpriteRenderer dressRenderer;

    private Body body;

    private void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Body>();
        dressRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        dressCollider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>();
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.CompareTag("Player"))
        {

            if (body.GetBodyRenderer != null)
            {
                SetDressToBody();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SetDressToBody()
    {
        body.SetBodySprite(dressRenderer.sprite);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is line 25? do you want us to count the lines from top of the code?

Comment: My bad. Line 25 is ```SetDressToBody();```

Comment: both of the above scripts are attached to the same gameobject?

Comment: No. They are different game objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the scripts `Body` and `Dress` are attached to different gameobjects, you can't get the `Body` component in your **Dress.cs** using the line:

```cs
body = GetComponent<Body>();
```

The above line can only get the reference to the component `Body` when the script **Body.cs** is attached to the same gameobject to which the script **Dress.cs** is attached.

To get the reference to `Body` component, declare it as a `public` variable in **Dress.cs**

```cs
public Body body;
```

Save the files and open Unity. In the inspector of the gameobject to which the script **Dress.cs** is attached, check for the field **Body**. Drag the gameobject containing the script **Body.cs** to the slot in the inspector

Answer (score 0):

if you click on error IDE will show exact line that caused error. I suppose it was

```
if (body.GetBodyRenderer != null)
```

because your body is null

Comment: The error is on the: ```body.SetBodySprite(dressRenderer.sprite);```
Is there any way to avoid null object reference?

Comment: What do you mean by "avoid"? Handle the case when it's null? Just check 
if(body != null && dressRenderer != null){
    body.SetBodySprite(dressRenderer.sprite);
}